# How to show BottomSheetDialog below toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm trying to achieve something that looks like in the image below.

[image]

It's a sheet shown from the top and is below the toolbar. It also has dimmed background.

I was able to show the sheet from the top as you can see [in this video](https://youtube.com/shorts/46lZDH8_sWU?feature=share) with the help of [this code](https://github.com/TechIsFun/AndroidTopSheet/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/github/techisfun/android/topsheet/TopSheetDialog.java)

How can I make the sheet appear below the toolbar with background dimming as shown in the picture?

Comment: I don't think a Dialog will work this way . better have a layout under Appbar and add BottomSheetBehavior to this layout ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [TopSheetBehavior](https://github.com/carlos-mg89/TopSheetBehavior) I am currently using this in one of my projects and it works perfectly. Thanks to [Carlos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/973919/xarlymg89) for this beautiful library.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="95dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

       <!-- Your toolbar content goes here -->

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This view is for black background when sheet expanded -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/sheetExpanded"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:background="#91000000"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TopSheetCustomView (Create Custom Top Sheet Content View)
        android:id="@+id/roomTopSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="110dp"
        app:layout_behavior="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.TopSheetBehavior" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If you want to add black background you can add slide callback

```kotlin
TopSheetBehavior.from(roomTopSheet (XML view id)).setTopSheetCallback(object :
TopSheetBehavior.TopSheetCallback() {
    override fun onStateChanged(topSheet: View, newState: Int) {
        // On Sheet State Changed
    }

    override fun onSlide(topSheet: View, slideOffset: Float, isOpening: Boolean?) {
        runCatching {
            sheetExpanded.alpha = (slideOffset * 100).toInt() / 100F
            if (slideOffset == 0F) sheetExpanded.hide() 
            else sheetExpanded.show()
        }
    }
})

sheetExpanded.setOnClickListener {
    TopSheetBehavior.from(roomTopSheet).state =
    TopSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
}
```

Also you need to add this code for make top sheet behind to app bar

```kotlin
roomTopSheet.bringToFront()
appBar.bringToFront()
```